# Deploy Apex Class to another Salesforce ORG via Metadata API?

Tags: rest, metadata

So I've been looking around to see if there is a way to push Apex Classes via the Metadata API, and I'm a little confused at the documentation. I've used the Eclipse plugin before, so I know that you can absolutely create Apex Classes through the API, I'm just not sure how to do that via Apex.

I've been reviewing this hear https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm. It looks like they have some fields that you can set the name, and some other fields, but it looks like all of the content is coming from the base64 encoding. Is there a way that I can send the content over without generating a zip file?

Use case is this - I have a need to have a custom button or tab that will call an apex class that will query for all apex classes and their logic, then push to another Salesforce org via the metadata API.

Comment: So you want to create your own "Change set" functionality. That's interesting.

Comment: In a way, yes. The theory is that it'll pull from another Salesforce org (or GIT) and pull all of the api accessible metadata into the new org.

Comment: There is a [Metadata REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_calls_intro.htm) that doesn't depend on ZIP files, as well as the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm), which is REST-based and uses similar interface.

Comment: Only Limitation is Tooling cant be used in Prod to deploy :)

Comment: I don't think we'll be using it to deploy in Prod, it'll only be used to deploy to sandboxes.

Comment: @sfdcfox I looked at that API that you linked, the examples don't seem to provide much for Apex Classes, just objects. Is there a way I can set the content of the Apex classes if I create the containers via the createMetadata() ?

Comment: @Ryan The tooling API is a full development system designed to be leveraged by IDEs, so it can do things like resolving symbol tables for a unit of code, etc. It takes a bit of digging to get all the info you need, but yeah, basically you create a container, then add your classes, etc as container members.

Comment: @Sfdcfox thanks for the info. I'm going to try and use the Tooling API as you suggested. I can see from the examples that it's pretty easy to create an apex class using strings that you can set, I'm going to try and do this dynamically. I'll attempt to see if I can query the body from the original org, then bind it to the new tooling api call to the destination org. I'll update this post as I go along so anyone in the future that has the question can refer to this. Thanks for all the help so far